# Nginx configured ssl certificate

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl

There is a web app (node js, ssr) and customers can create their own pages and customers should be able to use their own domain for this page with their uploaded certificate.

Where should I configure it - on nginx level or in node js?

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score -1):

I've found awesome solution and it is https://caddyserver.com/ that have awesome SSL/TLS support with automatic HTTPS.